# PHP PDO Binding part of the sql statement to something

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Why can't I do something like this (this is inside a function):

```
switch($a) {
case 'userStatus':
break;

case 'userCanEdit':
break;

case 'userCanView':
break;

default:
echo 'Unable to identify type';
return false;

$sqlUpdateId = 'update users set :sql = :status where userId = :id and code = :code';

$updateId->bindParam(':sql',$a);
}
```

Notice the `:sql` part? It's set above, and comes thru after passing thru a switch. But this will not work. Can only input values be bound? This'll save a lot of code.

Comment: Well it should not be possible, that is the whole idea. It should be seen as a variable outside the scope of SQL, otherwise SQL injection is still possible

Answer (score 2):

But you can do the following:

```
$allowedColumns = ('userStatus', 'userCanEdit', ...);
if (in_array($a, $allowedColumns)) {
    $sqlUpdateId = 'update users set ' . $a . ' = :status where userId = :id and code = :code';
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the way it now is, except that instead of an array, I use the switch :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot bind a column name, only the value.